# File_upload_preferences_model::get_upload_preferences() removed - What to use?

Tags: add-on-development, file-uploads

I've had a plugin for ExpressionEngine developed that uses the File_upload_preferences_model::get_upload_preferences() method, which is now removed.

Is there a way for me to update the plugin to reflect any newly added similar methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new method that replaces `get_upload_preferences` is called `get_file_upload_preferences`. All you need to do is change that method name in your code, the parameters should be the same.

Comment: Thank you. The two methods returns object and array, so I hade to change some code.